# Showing $b^r<b<b^s$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $0<r<1<s$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $b>1$

Tags: real-analysis

This question has been driving me crazy.

> Suppose $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$ are such that $0<r<1<s$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $b>1$. Show that $b^r<b<b^s$.

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed. My logic right now is that: if $b_1 < b_2$ and $b_2 < b^s_2$ then it follows that $b_1 < b^s_2$. I'm assuming a similar argument can be made for $b^r_0 < b_1$. I just don't know how to formally prove this, and I don't think the statement $b_2 < b^s_2$ is justified.

Comment: Please state the question you are trying to prove more clearly.

Comment: @NickR Sure. I've edited my post. I'm trying to show $b^r<b<b^s$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $1<b \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Perhaps I am confused. Pick $b = 2, r = 2, s = 1/2$ certainly all of these are now false.

Comment: @NickR Oh sorry. I left out another condition. My title should also include 0<r<1<s. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a rational $0 < r < 1$ be given. Then we have $r = n/m$ where $n/m$ are positive integers with $n < m$. We have $b^r < b$ if and only if $(b^r)^m < b^m$ which is equivalent to $b^n < b^m$.  Since $b > 1, m-n > 0$ we have $$b^{m-n} > 1$$
$$b^n b^{m-n} > b^n$$
$$b^m > b^n$$

A similar argument can be done with $s$.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea it would be this simple. Thank you so much!